# How can I analyze file and detect if the file is in H.264 video format?

Tags: c++, c, video, ffmpeg

I write software C/C++ to recover deleted files, and I need to identify files according to their binary content, so my question is there a simple way to know if a particular file is H.264 format video? is H.264 has an signature?

I saw the code of FFMPEG [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/avc.c#L27), but can it help me, how?

Comment: ffprobe can help you.

Comment: @Shark How can I use FFMPEG what function should I use? You can direct me more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that H.264 is not a file format, it is a video compression standard, and as such it can be found in multiple file formats. You can have a .f4v encoded with H.264 as much as you can have .mp4 with H.264.

So, how do you solve your issue? Well, I strongly advise you to use a library that does that for you. [libavformat](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/avformat_8h.html), for example, should do the trick (check the `AVStream` and `AVFormatContext` structures, and the `avformat_open_input` function).

Now, if you absolutely want to do it without libraries, you can check out the documentation for [each video container format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats) that supports H.264 to see how to retrieve the encoding information of the video stream, but expect this to take you at least a month or two.

Comment: I work with Visual Studio and can not compile `libavformat`, do you know a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find binaries to use with Visual Studio, but the guys from FFmpeg made a [wiki article](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MSVC) about compiling the sources with the Visual Compiler. If that doesn't do the trick, I guess you could also use another library, but I don't know any other, unfortunately. I think [libVLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/libvlc.html) could eventually do what you want, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 4):

For those who encounter this question but are looking for a cli solution you can use `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nw=1:nk=1 input.mkv
```

Outputs:

```
h264
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use FFmpeg - [`avformat_find_stream_info()`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/group__lavf__decoding.html#gad42172e27cddafb81096939783b157bb) should help you. An [there](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/transcoding_8c_source.html#l00048) is an example.