# Python OpenCV - Increase video fps

Tags: python, opencv

I have a video sequence composed of 3076 frames.

The original video at **10fps** lasts 307.6 seconds (or 5.12 minutes).

I want to convert the video in order to last 1.42 seconds at **29.98fps** using Python OpenCV.

How to accomplish this task?

Comment: why opencv? is the video an existing file or being created in opencv?

Comment: You're not trying to reduce fps. You're trying to increase fps.

Comment: IMHO a computer vision library is not the ideal tool for something that most likely involves just changing a few bytes in the header of the video file.

Comment: I would have expected a 3,076 frame video to last 307 seconds at 10 fps not 5.12 seconds.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45465730/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cv2.VideoWriter` function where you can adjust fps as per your requirement.

More details about the function [open CV video saver](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)

```
 out = cv2.VideoWriter(str(videoname+"AV.avi"),cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D'),  fps, (fw,fh))
```