# Generating synthetic testsrc video counting at 10 fps, first frame is duplicated

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to generate synthetic video using FFmpeg.

I want the frame rate to be 10 fps, and I want `testsrc` counter to advance every frame.

Problem:
When the output file is `mp4`, the first video frame is **duplicated** 10 times.

Question:
Is it a bug in FFmpeg, or a problem in the command line arguments?

---

I am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 10 -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=192x108:rate=1 -c:v libx264 vid.mp4
```

- The reason for setting `rate=1` is for the counter to advance on each frame.
  The generated source pattern is designed to advance the counter every second.
- The reason for setting `-r 10` before the input, is for "remuxing" the video at 10 fps, and ignoring the timestamps of the input.

I found the syntax in the following post: [Using ffmpeg to change framerate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462731/using-ffmpeg-to-change-framerate/45465730):

> Remux with new framerate
>
> `ffmpeg -y -r 24 -i seeing_noaudio.h264 -c copy seeing.mp4`

When the output file is `AVI` it's working correctly (first frame is not duplicated):

```
ffmpeg -y -r 10 -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=192x108:rate=1 -c:v libx264 vid.avi
```

When generating `AVI` at 1 fps, and Remux to `mp4` at 10 fps, there is a different problem:
The first and second frames are duplicated twice, and the last frame is missing.
Here are the commands:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=92x54:rate=1 -c:v libx264 -r 1 vid.avi
ffmpeg -y -r 10 -i vid.avi -c:v copy -r 10 vid.mp4
```

---

Parsing the `mp4` video to `PNG` images:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 %02d.png
```

Result:
[image]
The first frame is duplicated 10 times.

---

Parsing the `AVI` video to `PNG` images:
Result:
[image]
There are 10 frames as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely something to do with the initial timebase but I can't test for a few days. For now, use

```
ffmpeg -y                                    \
       -f lavfi                               \
       -i                                      \
        testsrc=duration=10:size=192x108:rate=1 \
       -vf                                       \
        setpts=N/10/TB                            \
       -r 10                                       \
       -c:v                                         \
        libx264                                      \
        vid.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working when moving the `-r 10` to the input: `ffmpeg -r 10 -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=192x108:rate=1 -vf setpts=N/10/TB -c:v libx264 vid.mp4`. I still don't understand if it's a bug in FFmpeg...