# Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0 during concatenation parts of the same video file

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video file `example.mp4`, and text file concat.txt:

```
file 'example.mp4'
outpoint 422.719
file 'example.mp4'
inpoint 422.719
outpoint 683.151
file 'example.mp4'
inpoint 688.151
outpoint 1014.349
file 'example.mp4'
inpoint 1019.349
```

I do:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy -y out.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy -y out.mp4
```

And get set of errors in both cases:

```
[mp4 @ 0x55a9a90ad980] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0;...
[mp4 @ 0x55a9a90ad980] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0;...
...
```

Also there are sound artifacts near the glue spots. They sound like beginning of the second part goes to the end of the first.

Comment: There is half a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462731/using-ffmpeg-to-change-framerate/45465730). Without re-encoding the solution works for video only (assuming video codec is `h264`). I tried similar solution for audio (`ac3` codec), but I am still getting the warning messages for the audio stream.

Comment: I came up with the following solution: I cut 4 part with: `ffmpeg -noaccurate_seek -ss START_TIME  -i 'example.mp4' -t END_TIME -c copy -y %d.mp4', add those files to the text file and glue with: 'ffmpeg -f concat -i TEXT_FILE -c copy -y result.mp4'