# ffmpeg. Artifacts after cut and concat of the same video file

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I cut the video using the following commands:

```
ffmpeg -i 'example.mp4' -ss 0 -t 640.509 -c copy -y o1.mp4
ffmpeg -i 'example.mp4' -ss 645.342 -t 424.195 -c copy -y o2.mp4
ffmpeg -i 'example.mp4' -ss 1074.37 -t 463.202 -c copy -y o3.mp4
ffmpeg -i 'example.mp4' -ss 1542.405 -t 295.6 -c copy -y o4.mp4
ffmpeg -i 'example.mp4' -ss 1842.838 -t 368.54 -c copy -y o5.mp4
ffmpeg -i 'example.mp4' -ss 2216.211 -c copy -y o6.mp4
```

After that I concat them with:

```
ffmpeg -auto_convert 1 -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy -y result.mp4
```

my concat.txt file:

```
file o1.mp4
file o2.mp4
file o3.mp4
file o4.mp4
file o5.mp4
file o6.mp4
```

The issue is: I'm getting a short artifacts in the beginning of each fragment in the `result.mp4` file.

During the concat I get the following:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb8db801400] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter177x    
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb8db801400] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter188x    
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb8e0000600] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter188x    
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb8db801400] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter189x    
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb8db801400] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter186x
```

Comment: In your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60117808/non-monotonous-dts-in-output-stream-00-during-concatenation-parts-of-the-same-v), I kind of recommended you to look for a solution without re-encoding (for getting better quality). What is the video codec, and audio codec of `example.mp4`?

Comment: Thank you for taking time. This solution is without re-encoding. h264/aac

Comment: no luck: [h264 @ 0x7f8e8d822600] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
    [h264 @ 0x7f8e8d822600] non-existing PPS 0 referenced 
    [h264 @ 0x7f8e8d822600] decode_slice_header error
    [h264 @ 0x7f8e8d822600] no frame!

Comment: In documentation: `The duration of each file is used to adjust the timestamps of the next file: if the duration is incorrect (because it was computed using the bit-rate or because the file is truncated, for example), it can cause artifacts. The duration directive can be used to override the duration stored in each file.`. I don't know how to use this information. It didn't help in my case.

Comment: I found [this explanation](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/23430). Make it simple: I moved -ss before -i and added `-avoid_negative_ts 1`. looks like it's working well for me.

Comment: I thought of a solution that decode (covert) the video to raw uncompressed format, split, concatenate, and encode (compress) the result. Good to know you found a solution.